# Как составить SQL запрос который будет сортировать, только по поступившим данным

Tags: sql, wpf

Например, имеем таблицу

> Имя|Фамилия|Телефон

И нужно построить SQL запрос по поступающим данным из текстбоксов программы
Как сортировать только по тем текстбоксам, в которые пользователь ввел значения?

Например:

1)У меня 3 текстбокса, я ввел только в текстбокс поиска по имени. Значит должен происходить только поиск по имени.

2)У меня 3 текстбокса, я ввел только в текстбокс поиска по имени и по телефону.
Значит должен происходить только поиск по имени и телефону, но безразлично, какая фамилия.

Подскажите, как реализовать данный функционал?

Единственное, что приходит на ум - проверять на IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace и в зависимости от результата применять соответствующий SQL запрос.Но при большем
количестве textbox'ов это будет громоздко...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Создайте в программе словарь в котором ключами будут поля вашей таблицы, а значениями текстбоксы

код

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox> dict = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>()
{
    { @"FName", this.tbFName },
    { @"LName", this.tbLName },
    { @"Text", this.tbText }
}
```

2. Секцию WHERE своего запроса соберите в отдельной функции, в которой будете проходится по этому словарю

код:

```
private string getWhere()
{
     string tmp = @"WHERE ";
     string result = string.Empty;

     foreach (var next in dict)
     {
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(next.Value.Text))
         {
             if (result != string.Empty) { result = result + @" and "; }
             result = result + string.Format("{0} = \'{1}\'", next.Key, next.Value.Text);
         }
     }

     if (result != string.Empty)
     {
         result = tmp + result;
     }
     return result;
}
```

3. Дергайте эту функцию, когда будете создавать свой запрос

Comment: SQL-инъекция не смущает? А в целом, конечно, подход вполне корректный

Comment: @Nikolay в вопросе ведь нет информации ни о приложении, ни о бд. Поэтому и даю самое простое решение.

Comment: Чтобы сделать вариант совсем динамическим, без словаря контролов, можно нужные контролы положить внутрь панели, а в методе `getWhere()` итерироваться по дочерним контролам этой панели нужного типа.

Comment: Спасибо за самый простой вариант. То, что нужно :)!